# How can I add the content of a span as a css class and remove the content?

Tags: html, css

I need this:
`<span class="fooBar>content</span>`

to be rendered into this:
`<span class="fooBar content></span>`

But only if fooBar is already added as a class to the span element and only using css or scss. Is this possible?

Edit: Since this appear not to be possible:

We are using material icons and now our UI/UX Design Teams wants to use custom icons. Because of this, we created our own icon font and what we want to achieve is, that there is no difference in using the icons.

With the material icon lib (https://github.com/marella/material-icons) we can use:

```
<span class="material-icons-outlined">add</span>
```

And then it will appear as an icon.

Even though I have created the font, the only way it works right now is if I put the icon I want to use as a class instead of the content, even though I recreated the fonts in css like they did in the material icons library.

What we want:

```
<span class="company-icons">custom</span>
```

I can't figure out how to do it the same way they did.

This is the code generated by fantasticon:

[image: Generated Code]

This code I had to add, so spans work at all:

[image: Added code]

Please ignore the red underlines, I changed to company name, with the original name, the files are found.

Usage:
[image: usage]

The lower one works, the upper doesn't.

Comment: No, CSS cannot modify HTML.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for this, can't do it with CSS alone.

Comment: Sorry I don´t get your question, you want to move "content" from inner html of the span to its class?

Comment: Can you show how you are importing the custom font into your application?

Assuming that you have imported the custom font correctly, then applied it to your span element using a class correctly, then there should be no reason as to why the 'custom' text isn't replaced in the rendered dom with your icon from your font,. assuming your icon font doesn't have any sort of issues either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to select the HTML elements you want. Next you will do the logic you want in JS.

```js
// Select all elements you want to transform (a class would be the most logic way)
let icons = document.querySelectorAll('.icon')

// Loop each icon
icons.forEach(function(icon) {
    // Add the innertext as a class
    icon.classList.add(icon.innerText);
    
    // Empty the current innertext
    icon.innerText = ''
})
```

```html
<div class="not-a-icon">Programming</div>
<div class="icon">is</div>
<div class="icon">fun!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm including it into a library used in several apps and I don't want to do this in every app.

Comment: Don't include into your library then but in the apps you want to implement it?

Comment: @Michael1312 well that is what you are going to have to do because there is no CSS that detects text. So either you code your stuff to add the class to start or you have to do something like the code above.